# Compressing and expanding graphs of $y=f(x)$

Tags: graphing-functions

Is $y=-\dfrac 12 f(x)$ equal to $-2y=f(x)$ and if so, does this indicate a vertical compression of $\dfrac 12$ and a reflection in the $y$-axis?

Comment: Yes and no.  The reflection from the $-$ sign is in the $x$-axis

Comment: Thank you! So there is a vertical compression by a factor of 1/2 and a reflection in the x-axis?

Comment: Think about it this way: $-f(x)$ is negating the *outputs* of the function, so all the $y$-values are negated, thus its flipped over the $x$-axis. $f(-x)$ negates the *input* of the function, so first, all the $x$-values are negated, so its flipped over the $y$-axis.

Answer (score 1):

$\dfrac 12f(x)$ is only a vertical compression of $f(x)$.

On the other hand, when you introduce the negative sign, $-\dfrac 12f(x)$ is a vertical compression, as well as a reflection over the $x$-axis!